# How to switch between two containers dependent on image size? CCC/HTML

Tags: html, css, image

Could anybody tell me how I would switch between two img containers depending on the size of the image?

At the moment I have one standard image container which displays imgs in a standard grid.

**CSS**

```
.rounded-image {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="http://*URL*/products/<?  =$cake['id']?>-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[<?=$cake['name_p']?>]"><img   src="http://*URL*/products/<?=$cake['id']?>-1.jpg" alt="<?=$cake['name']?>"   class="rounded-image" /></a></td>
```

*Note the URL has been obfuscated above.

I have various different image sizes running through the site - some where the width is greater than height and vice versa. At the moment, the 'landscape' images aren't being displayed proportional to the container. The image appears squashed.

I was thinking it would be sensible to have two containers to suit either portrait or landscape imgs. I'm just not entirely sure how to switch between the two...

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image Grid showing mismatched containers]

Thanks

EDITED

Comment: Can't you just add a CSS style to the images .rounded-image img { width: 100%; height: auto; } I can't quite imagine how the containers would differ? Could you provide a visual?

Comment: @СърГеоргиДемирев - I've added an image of the image grid, once adding your suggested styling to the CSS. It leaves one of the pictures smaller than the rest. Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I see, why don't you try using a jQuery plugin that will layout the pictures "Pinterest style" like Masonry or Isotope, that way they will arrange no matter what the height. Alternately you can add a style to the containers .rounded-image { min-heigh: ???px } that will ensure the height of the container is minimum that amount of pixels hence making them all look the same.

Comment: @СърГеоргиДемирев - I'll try one of those suggested plugins. Thanks